# Jquery load div shift

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am using the following to load a div after a successful ajax form submit.

```
  $('#randomdiv').load('somepage.html #randomdiv');
```

Everything is happening exactly how I want it to, except that when the button is first used to trigger the form submit, the div shifts down and over about 4 pixels in each directions. I am absolutely stumped to what would be the cause.

I am reloading the button using the same format.

```
 $('#submitbutton').load('somepage.html #submitbutton');
```

The button is also displaying the same shift. I have tried every other method of refresh, but I am needing to refresh database variables, and this method is the only one that is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting accidental nesting that is manifesting as a visual offset. From [the fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> ```
> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
> ```
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `ajax/test.html`, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

So when you do this:

```
$('#randomdiv').load('somepage.html #randomdiv');
```

You end up with this structure in your HTML:

```
<div id="randomdiv">
    <div id="randomdiv">
        whatever was in somepage.html's #randomdiv
    </div>
</div>
```

when you're probably expecting this:

```
<div id="randomdiv">
    whatever was in somepage.html's #randomdiv
</div>
```

You probably just need to restructure the HTML a bit to have an outer container element, say `#container`, that expects to have `#randomdiv` inserted into it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="randomdiv">
        ...
```

And then do `$('#container').load('somepage.html #randomdiv')` to put things in it.

Comment: I have tried that, but everything in my div disappears and I am left only with the #random div portion and the form submit stops functioning.

Comment: Actually, I reworked it and your suggestion worked. Thank you for the help. I will give you credit once I earn enough points.